# Specific loopy arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows

Here's the goal:

[image]

Here's where I'm at so far. I know how to do bending arrow, but not arrows that bend *that* far or *that*... specifically, I guess?

```latex
\tikzstyle{allocated} = [>=latex, thick, <-, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt]
\tikzstyle{requested} = [>=latex, thick, ->, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt, dashed]
\tikzstyle{process} = [circle, fill=gray!30]
\tikzstyle{resource} = [fill=cyan!30,
                            minimum width=1cm,
                            minimum height=0.7cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, resource] at (0, 0)   (r1) {};
        \node[anchor=south] at (r1.north) {$R_1$};
    \node[draw, resource] at (4, 0)   (r2) {};
        \node[anchor=south] at (r2.north) {$R_2$};

    \node[draw, process] at (0, -2)   (t1) {$T_1$};
    \node[draw, process] at (2, -2)   (t2) {$T_2$};
    \node[draw, process] at (4, -2)   (t3) {$T_3$};

    \path[allocated]
        (t2) edge (r1)
        (t2) edge (r2)
        (t3) edge (r2);

    \path[requested]
        (t1) edge (r1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(There are 2 kinds of arrows here, you might notice, dashed and plain, not seen in the diagram. That's because I'm trying to make the difference more visually apparent cuz I find it confusing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try `controls`, emm

```tex
\tikzstyle{allocated} = [>=latex, thick, <-, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt]
\tikzstyle{requested} = [>=latex, thick, ->, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt, dashed]
\tikzstyle{process} = [circle, fill=gray!30]
\tikzstyle{resource} = [fill=cyan!30,
                            minimum width=1cm,
                            minimum height=0.7cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, resource] at (0, 0)   (r1) {};
        \node[anchor=south] at (r1.north) {$R_1$};
    \node[draw, resource] at (4, 0)   (r2) {};
        \node[anchor=south] at (r2.north) {$R_2$};

    \node[draw, process] at (0, -2)   (t1) {$T_1$};
    \node[draw, process] at (2, -2)   (t2) {$T_2$};
    \node[draw, process] at (4, -2)   (t3) {$T_3$};

    \path[allocated]
        (t2) edge (r1)
        (t2) edge (r2)
        (t3) edge (r2);

    \path[requested]
        (t1) edge (r1);

    \draw[allocated] (t3) ..controls(5.5,1.5).. (r1);
    \draw[allocated] (r2) ..controls(2,-3.5).. (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's a solution, but probably not the best.